# Users able to delete own comments without Administer Comments Permission

Tags: php, drupal

I've installed this module and it works Great!! exactly what I needed.....but.......Now all comments are flat it seems the next logical step (well as far as my users tell me) is to have a permisson where users can delete their own comments. They have the ability to edit but not delete. the Administer Comments permission would obviously give them the ability to delete anyones comments (not desirable). A permission that just allowed own comment deletion would be great.

I just wish I had the brains to do it!

Comment: This is out of scope for this module.

Comment: But Ajax Comments stops working when a user tries to delete own comment or comments on own nodes.

Would you be so kind as to allow Ajax Comments to work with the above 2 modules?

Thanks!

Comment: got any ideas on this one I'm still very very stumped

BuZZ the limey

drupal n00b!
http://drupal.org/node/834200

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit comment and leave it empty.
as far as I remember, it should "delete" comment.
so, you can add just a hint (description) to comments, without needing to implement this functionality.

The other way to do it - write custom module. or look for comments_delete module;